# App crash as soon as file dialog opens - Qt6

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qt6

This is the code, it is directly from the documentation. As soon as I click on choose image, the file dialog opens and app hangs then crashes:

```
import QtCore
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    header: ToolBar {
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Choose Image...")
            onClicked: fileDialog.open()
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: image
        anchors.fill: parent
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        currentFolder: StandardPaths.standardLocations(StandardPaths.PicturesLocation)[0]
        onAccepted: image.source = selectedFile
    }
}
```

There are no specific errors as well.

Comment: I guess the problem is with `[0]` in `StandardPaths.standardLocations(StandardPaths.PicturesLocation)[0]`. What if your standard picture locations do not return any paths? Then you are trying to access the first item in a list which contains no items. Try to print out the contents of the list to see if there are any items at all.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager I checked and there are items there.

Comment: Does it crash also when you comment out that line with `currentFolder`?

Comment: Note there are two FileDialogs one from labs and one isn't can you confirm which one you're using?

Comment: @StephenQuan this ones from Qt.Quick.Dialogs